# My commandButton should not work but does, why?

Tags: jsf, netbeans, xhtml, commandbutton

I'm working in Java with JSF and CSS in NetBeans and I have a button that keeps working despite my best efforts to sabotage it.
I used a commandButton in one of my pages "boekEdit.xhtml" it was supposed to work like this:

in boekEdit.xhtml:

```
action="#{boekEditBean.goBack()}"
```

in boekEditBean.java:

```
public String goBack()
{
    return "goBack";
}
```

in faces.config.xml:

```
<navigation-rule>
  <from-view-id>/boekEdit.xhtml</from-view-id>
  <navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>goBack</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/boeken.xhtml</to-view-id>
  </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

This worked fine, but when I tried to edit this, I kept getting the same result.
I've deleted all of this, as well as every reference to the String "goBack" and replaced the button with one without an "action" component. However on pressing this button I still return to "boeken.xhtml". I already saved all and additionally tried:

- closing and opening browser/netbeans
- reboot the computer
- tried opening in a different browser
- debugger on line: public String goBack(){return "goBack";}

on pressing button it did not stop at this breakpoint (not sure if it should have)

can't figure this one out. Does someone have a clue what I should look for? If you need more code I'll gladly provide this but for the sake of your time I only put in the essentials.

plz help

Comment: Did you try doing a clean build of your project? And did you check there are no "old" versions of compiled classes/libraries in your build?

Comment: @Thomas already tried clean build, and no old versions in the build.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are accessing a newly deployed webapp? Aren't you by accident accessing something on a different server? (Happened to me once, looooong ago). Took me 4 hours to find out

Comment: @Kukeltje As far as I can tell there isn't one but it does seem likely that there is something like that. I just removed the xhtml, opened a new one with a new name with just one button without meaning and on click it did still return to the page "boeken.xhtml" also I now used another page as main one and it still returns to "boeken.xhtml" so it's not like it navigates to the main page.... Any way I can check for this? Already looked through the folders...